# Free groups: unique up to unique isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

A free group $F_S$ over a set $S$ is unique up to unique isomorphism. After reading [this answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49266/unique-up-to-unique-isomorphism) I think this means that if $F^\prime_S$ is another free group over $S$ then there exists exactly one isomorphism $\varphi : F_S \to F_S^\prime$ such that $\varphi \circ i = i^\prime$ where $i: S \to F_S$ and $i^\prime : S \to F^\prime_S$ are the inclusions.

Why is uniqueness of the isomorphism interesting at all? Wouldn't it be good enough to know that all free groups over $S$ are isomorphic to define free groups?

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough *for what*?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Enough to define what a free group is.

Comment: But the definition of free groups is completely independent of the fact that they are unique up to unique isomorphism: the latter is a property that one proves *after* we define what a free group i and even after we prove that they actually exist.

Comment: I think he is asking why "unique up to unique isomorphism" is a property worth talking about. I'm not really sure myself(though I've been told it is an important property). Mr. Kent, can you verify if this is what you're asking?

Comment: @JohnStalfos Thank you, I'm asking both: what is means and why it's worth talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One reason you are interested in "unique up to unique isomorphism" is that it makes things more "canonical."

Consider for example the following true fact: every $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

However, except for $n=0$, the isomorphism is neither unique nor "canonical": if I go home and do computations based on my favorite isomorphism and I tell you the answer, and you go home and you do your computations based on *your* favorite isomorphism, and then we come back tomorrow and describe our results, in order to translate one result into "the language of the other" we need to find out what *my* favorite isomorphism is, what *your* favorite isomorphism is, and perform the entire translations in order to compare "my" translation into $\mathbb{R}^n$ with yours and find out if we are both correct.

However, when there is a *canonical* choice of isomorphism, then we can simply both go home and translate (via this unique isomorphism), and then present the results the next day. They *must* match, because there is essentially only one way to translate.

(Canonicity is very useful; for instance, that is one reason why, still talking about linear algebra, the isomorphism in finite dimension between a vector space and its double dual is so much more important than the isomorphism between a vector space and its dual. The former is canonical, while the latter is not.)

From a point of view of category theory, uniqueness up to unique isomorphism allows for easy functorial properties to be derived, whereas merely isomorphic means a lot more book-keeping is needed, and it may be impossible to state a "coordinate-free" functorial property (where I'm thinking of 'coordinate-free' somewhat fuzzily to refer to not having to invoke specific, arbitrarily chosen isomorphisms to state or prove them).

Comment: Hi @Arturo. I was wondering if you would tell me whether my understanding is correct: If e.g. we're in the category of sets and $A$ is an initial object in Set then it's unique up to isomorphism which means that if $B$ is another initial object then $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic? That is, any two initial objects in a category are isomorphic. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I think the answer is yes.

Comment: @ClarkKent: Sorry, I didn't see the question. Yes, in any category, two initial objects are isomorphic via a unique isomorphism: if $I$ and $I'$ are both initial, then there is a unique map $f\colon I\to I'$ (because $I$ is initial), a unique map $g\colon I'\to I$ (because $I'$ is initial), and so $f\circ g\colon I'\to I'$ must be the unique map $I'\to I'$ (which is $\mathrm{id}_{I'}$, and $g\circ f\colon I\to I$ must be the unique map $I\to I$ (which is $\mathrm{id}_I$), so $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms, and they are the unique isomorphisms. In $\mathbf{Sets}$, $\varnothing$ is the initial obj

Answer (score 2):

Uniqueness up to unique isomorphism implies that there is no automorphism $f:F_S\to F_S$ which is the identity on the image of $i:S\to F_S$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to understand: reading [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property#Properties) makes it sound as if *essentially unique* is a synonym of *unique up to unique isomorphism*, is this right?

Comment: Then maybe "unique up to unique isomorphism" means that for two free groups $(i, F_S), (i^\prime, F_S^\prime)$ there is an isomorphism $\varphi: F_S \to F_S^\prime$ such that $\varphi \circ i = i^\prime$?

Comment: @ClarkKent: There is a *unique* isomorphism with that property; and that follows from the universal property of the free group.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you!