# Complexification of realification: Unnecessary computation of eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I started studying the book of Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction. I tried studying [backwards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme) as much as possible, but I have been stuck on the concepts of [almost complex structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure) and [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). I have studied several books and articles on the matter including ones by [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Jordan Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf), [Gregory W. Moore](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/%7Egmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf), [Steven Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285), [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), [Gauthier](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319115108).

I have several questions on the concepts of almost complex structures and complexification. Here is one:

**Question**: Below, I describe what I understand is happening in [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834) ([12.13 of Part I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZawh.png)), where the authors prove for any $\mathbb C$-vector space $L$, $L_{\mathbb R}^{\mathbb C} \cong L \bigoplus \overline L$ (I also asked about this isomorphism [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521938/in-what-way-is-l-mathbb-r-mathbb-c-more-like-l-bigoplus-overline-l).) Also, I base my understanding on Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction ([Chapter 1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P19bj.png)). **Is my understanding, given in the two parts as follows, correct?**

**Part 0. Assumptions, definitions, notations**:

1. **Complex structure on map definition** : See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520648/complexification-of-a-map-under-nonstandard-complexifications-of-vector-spaces).
2. On $L_{\mathbb R}^2$, we have almost complex structure $J(l,m):=(-m,l)$. $J$ is [canonical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure#Direct_sum) in the sense that we define complexification $(L_{\mathbb R})^{\mathbb C}$ of $L_{\mathbb R}$ with respect to $J$: $(L_{\mathbb R})^{\mathbb C} := (L_{\mathbb R}^2,J)$. Similarly, we have complexification $f^{\mathbb C}$ of $f \in End_{\mathbb R}(L_{\mathbb R})$ defined with respect to the canonical $J$: $f^{\mathbb C} := (f \oplus f)^J$.

- 2.1. For every $f \in End_{\mathbb R}(L_{\mathbb R})$, $f \oplus f$ commutes with $J$  i.e. $f^{\mathbb C} := (f \oplus f)^J$ is $\mathbb C$-linear.

3. Let $i^{\sharp}$ be the unique almost complex structure on $L_{\mathbb R}$ such that $L=(L_{\mathbb R},i^{\sharp})$.
4. Let $\hat i := i^{\sharp} \oplus i^{\sharp}$ such that $(\hat i)^J = (i^{\sharp})^{\mathbb C}$. Then $\hat i$ is another almost complex structure on $L_{\mathbb R}^2$.

- 4.1. By (2.1), $\hat i$ and $J$ commute, i.e. both $(\hat i)^J$ and $J^{\hat i}$ are $\mathbb C$-linear. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524239/eigenvalues-and-eigenspaces-of-almost-complex-structures-under-each-other) for related question.)

**Part I of my understanding**:

5. The authors compute the eigenvalues of $J^{\hat i}$ and not $(\hat i)^J$. Then, they compute the corresponding eigenspaces.
6. We know 'eigenspaces are subspaces', so if someone were to ask

   > Why do the authors have to explain why $L^{1,0}$ and $L^{0,1}$ are $\mathbb C$-subspaces of $(L_{\mathbb R})^{\mathbb C}$?,

   then the answer would be:

   > We know $L^{1,0}$ and $L^{0,1}$ are $\mathbb C$-subspaces of $(L_{\mathbb R}^2,\hat i)$ by "eigenspaces are subspaces", but we want to also show that $L^{1,0}$ and $L^{0,1}$ are $\mathbb C$-subspaces of $(L_{\mathbb R}^2,J) = (L_{\mathbb R})^{\mathbb C}$.

**Part II of my understanding**: It is unnecessary for the authors to compute the eigenvalues of $J^{\hat i}$ and then show that the eigenspaces are $\mathbb C$-subspaces of $(L_{\mathbb R}^2,J) = (L_{\mathbb R})^{\mathbb C}$.

7. The eigenvalues of $J^{\hat i}$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $(\hat i)^J$. The corresponding eigenspaces also have the same underlying sets. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524239/eigenvalues-and-eigenspaces-of-almost-complex-structures-under-each-other) for related question.)
8. By (7), the authors could have directly computed eigenvalues $(\hat i)^J$ and corresponding eigenspaces. Then, there is no need to explain why said eigenspaces would be $\mathbb C$-subspaces of $(L_{\mathbb R}^2,J) = (L_{\mathbb R})^{\mathbb C}$.

- 8.1. [Note](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518285/infinite-dimensional-vector-space-has-almost-complex-structure-if-and-only-if-it): An $\mathbb R$-vector space $A$ has an almost complex structure $H$ if and only if $A=B_{\mathbb R}$ for some non-unique $\mathbb C$-vector space $B$, such as $B=(A,H)$.
- 8.2. By (8.1), I believe (8) is precisely what Huybrechts ([Chapter 1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P19bj.png)) does except Huybrechts uses arbitrary almost complex structure '$I$' on '$V$' instead of specifically what would be $i^{\sharp}(v): = iv$ on $V$, viewed as the realification of some $\mathbb C$-vector space $L$, i.e. viewed as $V = L_{\mathbb R}$. Furthermore, the 'i', '$I$' and '$I^{\mathbb C}$' of Huybrechts correspond, respectively, to the $J$, $i^{\sharp}$ and $(i^{\sharp})^{\mathbb C}$ of Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this has an answer:

Yes, it is correct.