# Restriction of complexification is almost complex but not conversely?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I started studying the book of Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction. I tried studying [backwards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme) as much as possible, but I have been stuck on the concepts of [almost complex structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure) and [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). I have studied several books and articles on the matter including ones by [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Jordan Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf), [Gregory W. Moore](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/%7Egmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf), [Steven Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285), [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), [Gauthier](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319115108)

I have several questions on the concepts of almost complex structures and complexification. Here are some:

---

**Notations**: Let $V$ be a $\mathbb C$-vector space. Let $V_{\mathbb R}$ be the realification of $V$. For any almost complex structure $I$ on $V_{\mathbb R}$, denote by $(V_{\mathbb R},I)$ as the unique $\mathbb C$-vector space whose complex structure is given $(a+bi) \cdot v := av + bI(v)$.

- Let $W$ be an $\mathbb R$-vector space. Let $W^{\mathbb C}$ denote the complexification of $W$ given by $W^{\mathbb C} := (W^2,J)$, where $J$ is the canonical almost complex structure on $W^2$ given by $J(v,w):=(-w,v)$.
- For any map $f: V_{\mathbb R} \to V_{\mathbb R}$ and for any almost complex structure $I$ on $V_{\mathbb R}$, denote by $f^I$ as the unique map $f^I: (V_{\mathbb R}, I) \to (V_{\mathbb R}, I)$ such that $(f^I)_{\mathbb R} = f$. With this notation, the conditions '$f$ is $\mathbb C$-linear with respect to $I$' and '$f$ is $\mathbb C$-anti-linear with respect to $I$' are shortened to, respectively, '$f^I$ is $\mathbb C$-linear' and '$f^I$ is $\mathbb C$-anti-linear'.
- The complexification, under $J$, of any $g \in End_{\mathbb R}W$ is $g^{\mathbb C} := (g \oplus g)^J$, i.e. the unique $\mathbb C$-linear map on $W^{\mathbb C}$ such that $(g^{\mathbb C})_{\mathbb R} = g \oplus g$.

**Assumptions**: Let $H$ be an almost complex structure on $V_{\mathbb R}^2$. Suppose $H^J$ is $\mathbb C$-linear.

---

**Questions**:

1. Suppose $H^J = f^{\mathbb C} \in End_{\mathbb C}(V_{\mathbb R})^{\mathbb C}$, for some $f \in End_{\mathbb R}V_{\mathbb R}$. Restrict domain of $H$ to $V_{\mathbb R} \times 0$ to get $H|_{V_{\mathbb R} \times 0}: V_{\mathbb R} \times 0 \to (V_{\mathbb R})^2$. Observe that $image(H|_{V_{\mathbb R} \times 0}) \subseteq V_{\mathbb R} \times 0$ such that we can define $(H|_{V_{\mathbb R} \times 0})^{\tilde{}}: V_{\mathbb R} \times 0 \to V_{\mathbb R} \times 0$.

Is $(H|_{V_{\mathbb R} \times 0})^{\tilde{}}$ an almost complex structure on $V_{\mathbb R} \times 0$?

- Guess: I think yes because: $f$ is an almost complex structure on $V_{\mathbb R}$ by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524276/questions-on-the-complexification-of-a-map). Then (or even equivalently), $f \oplus 0$ is an almost complex structure on $V_{\mathbb R} \times 0$. Finally, $(H|_{V_{\mathbb R} \times 0})^{\tilde{}} = f \oplus 0$.

2. Suppose $image(H|_{V_{\mathbb R} \times 0}) \subseteq V_{\mathbb R} \times 0$ and $image(H|_{0 \times V_{\mathbb R}}) \subseteq 0 \times V_{\mathbb R}$ such that we can define $(H|_{V_{\mathbb R} \times 0})^{\tilde{}}$ and $(H|_{0 \times V_{\mathbb R}})^{\tilde{}}$. Suppose $(H|_{V_{\mathbb R} \times 0})^{\tilde{}}$ and $(H|_{0 \times V_{\mathbb R}})^{\tilde{}}$ are almost complex structures on, respectively, $V_{\mathbb R} \times 0$ and $0 \times V_{\mathbb R}$. Is $H^J$ not necessarily the complexification of some $f \in End_{\mathbb R}V_{\mathbb R}$, i.e. $H^J=f^{\mathbb C}$ is not necessarily true?

- Guess: Based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524276/questions-on-the-complexification-of-a-map), I think we could have $H=f \oplus g$ and $f \ne g$. Therefore, I think yes because even though $(H|_{V_{\mathbb R} \times 0})^{\tilde{}} = f \oplus 0$ and $(H|_{0 \times V_{\mathbb R}})^{\tilde{}} = 0 \oplus g$ for some $f,g \in End_{\mathbb R}V_{\mathbb R}$, we don't know that $f=g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my guess to Question 1 is correct, but my guess to Question 2 is incorrect.

For Question 2: I think the answer is no i.e. $H^J = f^{\mathbb C}$ for some $f$: We indeed have $H=f \oplus g$ but then because $H^J$ is $\mathbb C$-linear, we'll get that $f=g$ by [II.6.1 here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520648/complexification-of-a-map-under-nonstandard-complexifications-of-vector-spaces). Note that $f$ is the unique map such that $(H|_{V_{\mathbb R} \times 0})^{\tilde{}} = f \oplus 0$.