# Uniqueness of Dual Objects in Monoidal Categories

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I trying to understand the proof of Proposition 2.10.5 from the book: TENSOR CATEGORIES, by P. Etingof, S. Gelaki, D. Nikshych, and V. Ostrik, See http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/egnobookfinal.pdf.

Proposition 2.10.5. If $X\in \mathcal{C}$ has a left (respectively, right) dual object, then
it is unique up to a unique isomorphism.

Something I did not understand is why the three small squares of the following diagram commute?
[image]

where $e_1, c_1, e_2, c_2$ the corresponding evaluation and coevaluation morphisms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take the top left square.  We can rewrite it as
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_1^*\otimes 1\otimes 1 @>{id\otimes id\otimes c_1}>> X_1^*\otimes 1\otimes (X\otimes X_1^*)\\
@V{id\otimes c_2\otimes id}VV @V{id\otimes c_2\otimes id}VV \\
X_1^*\otimes (X\otimes X_2^*)\otimes 1 @>{id\otimes id\otimes c_1}>> X_1^*\otimes(X\otimes X_2^*)\otimes(X\otimes X_1^*)
\end{CD}$$
where $1$ is the unit object.  Commutativity of this square is now immediate from the fact that $\otimes$ is a bifunctor.

The other two squares are similar: once you explicitly write out the unit objects rather than implicitly eliminating them as is done in the original diagram, you are just using the functoriality of $\otimes$.

Comment: Thank you Eric! This is very nice explanation. I think there is a typo: the right vertical arrow $id \otimes c_2 \otimes c_1$ should be $id \otimes c_2 \otimes id$.

Comment: Oops, yes, corrected now.

Comment: Could you tell me why the triangle in the upper right corner commutes by axiom (2.43) applied to X_2 ^* (that what the authors say)?

Comment: The upper right triangle is just (2.43) tensored with $id:X_1^*\to X_1^*$ on both sides.  If it helps, the diagonal map can be labelled as $id\otimes id\otimes id$ rather than just $id$.

Comment: Perfect! . Thank you Eric!