# Unique isomorphisms and universal properties

Tags: category-theory, field-theory, integral-domain, universal-property

Having not studied category theory, I'm trying to piece together without using category theory what is meant when an algebraic structure is said to *possess a universal property* or be unique *up to unique isomorphism*.

I don't understand [Qiaochu Yuan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49266/unique-up-to-unique-isomorphism?lq=1) since it uses the notion of a universal property, which I'm having trouble finding a definition for that isn't worded in terms of category theory and/or the phrase "unique up to unique isomorphism." For example, on the [Universal Property Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property), the only formal definition that seems not to be worded in terms of category theory says "Universal properties define objects uniquely up to a unique isomorphism."

Here's something I do understand: In my abstract algebra class, we said that

> given an integral domain $D$, a **field of quotients of $D$** is a field $Q$ such that there is an embedding $i:D\hookrightarrow Q$ where $\forall q\in Q$, $\exists a,b\in D: q = i(a)(i(b))^{-1}$.

We showed that we can construct a field of quotients of an arbitrary integral domain $D$ using equivalence classes of $D\times D\setminus\{0\}$. We then proved the following theorem:

> Let $D$ be an integral domain and let $Q$ be a field of quotients of $D$ with the embedding $i:D\hookrightarrow Q$. If $F$ is a field such that there is an embedding $f:D\hookrightarrow F$, then there is a unique embedding $\overline f:Q \hookrightarrow F$ such that $\overline f\circ i = f$.

**Is this a universal property? If so, is it because of the following corollary?**

> Let $Q$ be a field of quotients of $D$ with the embedding $i:D\hookrightarrow Q$, and let $Q'$ be another field of quotients of $D$ with the embedding $i':D\hookrightarrow Q'$. Then there is a unique isomorphism $\overline{i'}: Q\hookrightarrow Q'$ such that $\overline{i'}\circ i = i'$.

**Is this when we would say $Q$ is unique up to unique isomorphism?**

Comment: Yes, this is a universal property: it says that the inclusion of an integral domain into its field of fractions is universal among inclusions from an integral domain into a field. More abstractly, it says that field of fractions is left adjoint to the forgetful functor from the category of fields to the category of integral domains and *injective* homomorphisms (this part is crucial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Products in many categories are said to possess a universal mapping property- formally, a product of two objects (say $A$ and $B$), is another object (say $P$) along with two arrows: $p_1:P \to A$ and $p_2:P \to B$ such that if $C$ is *any other object* (in our category), along with any pair of arrows, $f_1:C \to A, f_2: C \to B$, then *there exists* a UNIQUE arrow $\phi:C \to P$ such that:

$p_1\circ\phi = f_1\\p_2\circ\phi = f_2.$

The "baby example" of this construction is the cartesian product in the category $\mathbf{Set}$. Indeed, if we set, for two sets $A,B$:

$P = \{(a,b): a \in A, b \in B\}$, and take:

$p_1((a,b)) = a\\p_2((a,b)) = b,$

Then given any pair of maps $f_1:C \to A, f_2:C \to B$ for an abitrary set $C$, we can let:

$\phi(c) = (f_1(c),f_2(c))$, for any $c \in C$, and it's clear we have:

$(p_1\circ\phi)(c) = p_1(\phi(c)) = p_1(f_1(c),f_2(c)) = f_1(c)$ for ALL $c \in C$, and similarly:

$(p_2\circ \phi)(c) = f_2(c)$.

So certainly the map $\phi$ *exists* (for "this product"). On the other hand, if we have a map $\psi: C \to A \times B$ such that:

$p_1 \circ \psi = f_1$ and $p_2\circ \psi = f_2$, then from $p_1\circ \psi = f_1$ we know that:

$\psi(c) = (f_1(c),-)$, and similarly we know that $\psi(c) = (-,f_2(c))$, that is: $\psi$ has to be $\phi$, so $\phi$ is unique.

Now it should be pretty clear that this isn't "the only product" we can make: for example, we could take:

$P' = B \times A$ with $p_1:P' \to A$ given by $p_1'((b,a)) = a$, and similarly for $p_2'$.

In this case, we have two unique maps $\phi: P \to P'$, and $\phi': P' \to P$, and since $\phi((a,b)) = (b,a)$ and $\phi'((b,a)) = (a,b)$ fulfil the requirements, they must be the maps the universal property describes. Here, it's clear these are isomorphisms (in $\mathbf{Set}$, isomorphisms are just bijections), as these maps are inverses of each other.

The universal property invoked here is often paraphrased as: "the product map (what we are calling $\phi$, and is often written $f_1 \times f_2$) factors through the projections (what we are calling $p_1,p_2$)".

Now, it's "intuitively clearer" to regard the cartesian product of sets to be "the product" of $A$ and $B$. Note how the emphasis is on the elements in each ordered pair. In the construction above, the emphasis is on the mapping $\phi$, and the projection maps $p_1,p_2$, we don't even "look inside" the sets to see who lives there.

---

There is a similar factorization happening in your field of fractions example: any embedding $f$ of $D$ in any field $F$ factors through the embedding $i: D \to Q$. This captures (in this case) the sense of $Q$ being the "smallest" field we can insert $D$ into.